# Raw Buffer data play in audio tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, socket.io

I am making a web application where I am streaming the users microphone audio to a NODE JS server using socket IO and then re broadcasting the data.

```
<Buffer 59 00 76 00 92 00 a0 00 aa 00 b1 00 aa 00 92 00 7c 00 74 00 75 00 7e 00 8f 00 9d 00 9c 00 98 00 94 00 85 00 7c 00 8a 00 8f 00 6c 00 4f 00 5d 00 67 00 48 ...>
```

this is what I am sending and then recieving on all clients (via the log). IS it possible to then take that buffer and put it in some sort of audio container and play it in an HTML audio tag?

I tried taking the buffer obj and  making an object URL BLOB but it did not work.

```
  var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
```

should I push all the buffered data into an array? it would make sense so that the client could play it back but how can I take raw data and turn it into audio?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting finishing touches on a project to stream audio from node.js which is rendered in the browser by web audio - nothing out of the box that I've found - it involves setting up an audio context with its playback callback getting fed the buffers received via web sockets

Comment: been working on it all day. I am almost there. it is a major pain. I am just having an issue with the play back. I can send and recieve the buffer but I cannot get it to render again.